# Nodejs: Handshake terminated by server: 403 rabbitmq

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I am trying to connect to rabbitmq broker (**rabbitmq-server-3.8.0**) by nodejs and `amqplib/callback_api` library so after install `amqplib` library with :

`npm i amqplib`

I wrote this code :

```
const amqp = require("amqplib/callback_api");

amqp.connect('amqp://guest:guest@xxxx:5672', (err, conn) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    else console.log(`Connect to brocker success!`);
})
```

As official site say:

> By default, the guest user is prohibited from connecting from remote hosts; it can only connect over a loopback interface (i.e. localhost).
>
> It is possible to allow the guest user to connect from a remote host by setting the loopback_users configuration to none.

In `%APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\` location of my broker server it did not exist `rabbitmq.conf` file so i'd created this file  just by this content:

`loopback_users = none`

```
C:\Users\tazik.WIN-LKH5BTVHRCM\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is A852-F618

 Directory of C:\Users\tazik.WIN-LKH5BTVHRCM\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ

10/13/2019  11:39 AM    <DIR>          .
10/13/2019  11:39 AM    <DIR>          ..
10/12/2019  02:05 PM                 3 advanced.config
10/13/2019  11:41 AM    <DIR>          db
10/12/2019  02:07 PM                23 enabled_plugins
10/13/2019  10:37 AM    <DIR>          log
10/13/2019  10:22 AM                21 rabbitmq.conf
               3 File(s)             47 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  116,768,235,520 bytes free

C:\Users\tazik.WIN-LKH5BTVHRCM\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ>
```

Now after run nodejs code i still got this error:

```
2019-10-13 10:37:46.818 [info] <0.895.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.895.0> (94.182.192.28:25759 -> *********:5672)
2019-10-13 10:37:46.834 [error] <0.895.0> Error on AMQP connection <0.895.0> (94.182.192.28:25759 -> ******:5672, state: starting):
PLAIN login refused: user 'guest' can only connect via localhost
2019-10-13 10:37:46.849 [info] <0.895.0> closing AMQP connection <0.895.0> (94.182.192.28:25759 -> ******:5672)
```

Comment: The config file name should be `rabbitmq.conf` not `rabbitmq.config`

Comment: I changed it but i still got `ACCESS_REFUSED` error @Molda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you restarted after configuration? Also, check if RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE env is set to the location you placed the config file:

Open the "RabbitMQ Command Prompt (sbin dir)"

```
.\rabbitmq-service.bat stop

.\rabbitmq-service.bat remove
```

Run the following commands in the previous shell:

```
.\rabbitmq-service.bat install

.\rabbitmq-service.bat start
```

After that, you should be able to connect

Comment: How could i check `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE env` is set? @SandeepPatel

Comment: open cmd  and run  `echo %RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE%`  also see this https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/content/comp_environment/configuring_nuke/environment_variables.html

Comment: I see my config location in `rabbitmqctl environment` command on console `{windows_service_config,
          "C:/Users/tazik.WIN-LKH5BTVHRCM/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/rabbitmq.conf"}]},` .thanks bro @SandeepPatel